# Formatting number in python to bank account format

Tags: python, html, flask

I have tried looking around finding out how to format a number in python to this specific format. Formatting a number to a currency format was pretty easy to figure out but doing this was not.

```
<td>{{ "{:,.2f} NOK".format(acc['AccountBalance']) }}</td>
```

So I simply want to format 12345678901 to 1234.56.78901. I want to use this in my flask template website. Every number is always 11 digits, and it should be formatted as 4 digits period 2 digits period 5 digits period.

EDIT: This is being used in a Flask template, on numbers retrieved from an SQLite table and put into a list. It is the accs['ID'] that is getting this formatting done on it.

```
accs = db.execute(
        'SELECT a.ID, ownerID, AccountBalance, AccountName'
        ' FROM atbl_bank_accounts a JOIN atbl_system_users u ON a.ownerID = u.ID'
        ' WHERE a.ownerID = ?',
        (g.user['ID'],)
    ).fetchall()
```

This again is posted in to a table on the website using flask template as so:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-borderless mt-5">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-2" scope="col">Account Number</th>
        <th class="col-4" scope="col">Account Name</th>
        <th class="col-4" scope="col">Amount left</th>
        <th class="col-2" scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for acc in accs %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ acc['ID'] }}</th>
        <td>{{ acc['AccountName'] }}</td>
        <!--<td>{{ acc['AccountBalance'] }}</td>-->
        <td>{{ "{:,.2f} NOK".format(acc['AccountBalance']) }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit name of account"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Transfer money from account"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete account"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

So I either need a solution that works straight in the HTML or in the python script. Apologies for not being clear enough.

I did search a fair bit around, but if I skipped an article about this I'm sorry.
Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: What are the rules? Always four digits *on-the-left* and five digits *on-the-right*?

Comment: Yeah. Every number is always 11 digits, and it should be formatted as 4 period 2 period 5 period. If possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to NoNickAvailable and wwii for the tips.
Since I was using this is with a flask template and for loop, I couldn't use wwii's answer directly. With help from [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380360/replacing-value-in-all-cursor-rows), I managed to make a working version.

I retrive the data from the database as follows:

```
accs = db.execute(
        'SELECT a.ID, ownerID, AccountBalance, AccountName'
        ' FROM atbl_bank_accounts a JOIN atbl_system_users u ON a.ownerID = u.ID'
        ' WHERE a.ownerID = ?',
        (g.user['ID'],)
    ).fetchall()
```

Then I had to use `dict`:

```
IDrows = [dict(row) for row in accs]
```

Then to format the numbers with my very specific format I used what wwii and NoNickAvailable answered:

```
for i in IDrows:
        i['ID'] = '.'.join((str(i['ID'])[:4],str(i['ID'])[4:-5],str(i['ID'])[-5:]))
```

The numbers were than all individually formatted and easily inserted into my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-borderless mt-5">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-2" scope="col">Account Number</th>
        <th class="col-4" scope="col">Account Name</th>
        <th class="col-4" scope="col">Amount left</th>
        <th class="col-2" scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for acc in IDrows %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ acc['ID'] }}</th>
        <td>{{ acc['AccountName'] }}</td>
        <!--<td>{{ acc['AccountBalance'] }}</td>-->
        <td>{{ "{:,.2f} NOK".format(acc['AccountBalance']) }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit name of account"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Transfer money from account"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete account"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn the integer to a str and use slices along with `join`.

```
In [22]: p = 12345678901

In [23]: q = str(p)

In [24]: '.'.join((q[:4],q[4:-5],q[-5:]))
Out[24]: '1234.56.78901'
```

Or you could use slice objects which is basically the same thing but you get to name them.

```
In [33]: first, middle, last = slice(0,4),slice(4,-5),slice(-5,None)

In [34]: '.'.join((q[first],q[middle],q[last]))
Out[34]: '1234.56.78901'
```

Comment: Tried this and couldn't make it work with what I have. Made edit to post, may help clarify what I am looking for. Apologies.

Comment: for me this works: '.'.join((str(acc['ID'])[:4],str(acc['ID'])[4:-5],str(acc['ID'])[-5:]))